# Xpath selection of all attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the xml below in a c# class.

```
string xml =@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<call method='importCube'>
<credentials login='sampleuser@company.com' password='my_pwd' instanceCode='INSTANCE1'/>
<importDataOptions version='Plan' allowParallel='false' moveBPtr='false'/>
```

I need to update the XML held within the node attributes i.e.

```
string xml =@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<call method='importCube'>
<credentials login='testuser@test.com' password='userpassword' instanceCode='userinstance'/>
<importDataOptions version='Actual' allowParallel='true' moveBPtr='true'/>
```

I've written code to do this :

```
// instantiate XmlDocument and load XML from string
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

// get a list of nodes
XmlNodeList aNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/call/credentials");


// loop through all nodes
foreach (XmlNode aNode in aNodes)
{
    // grab the attribute
    XmlAttribute idLogin = aNode.Attributes["login"];
    XmlAttribute idPass = aNode.Attributes["password"];
    XmlAttribute idInstance = aNode.Attributes["instanceCode"];

    idLogin.Value = "myemail.com";
    idPass.Value = "passtest";
    idInstance.Value = "TestInstance";



    }
```

It works but the issue at the minute is that I have to repeat the whole code block for each node path i.e.

```
XmlNodeList aNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/call/importDataOptions");
....
```

There has to be a better way.   Any ideas how I can rip through the attributes in 1 pass?

Comment: I should have added that the XML is bigger than what I've shown with more nodes.

Comment: foreach (XmlElement aNode in aNodes) ... aNode.SetAttribute("login", "myemail.com"); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just using a cast to `XmlElement` could help you to reduce your code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

foreach (XmlElement credential in doc.SelectNodes("/call/credentials"))
{
    credential.SetAttribute("login"       , "myemail.com" );
    credential.SetAttribute("password"    , "passtest"    );
    credential.SetAttribute("instanceCode", "TestInstance");
}
```

Another option is to create an object structure which resembles your XML vocabulary and deserialize your input into that objects, but it seems overkill.

**EDIT**: Per your comment, you could go with:

```
foreach (XmlElement node in doc.SelectNodes("/call/*")) // it's case sensitive
{
    switch(node.Name)
    {
        case "credentials":
            node.SetAttribute("login"       , "myemail.com" );
            node.SetAttribute("password"    , "passtest"    );
            node.SetAttribute("instanceCode", "TestInstance");
            break;
        case "importDataOptions":
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unexpected node: "+node.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I still have to loop down a different node path i.e. /call/importDataOptions.    I tried selecting nodes /Call/* but no joy.